# What kind of knife is this and where is it from?

Tags: identification

I was given this knife by someone who says it is an antique. This person is also very old and forgetful. **Can anybody identify this knife?**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it might be a [serrated Jambiya dagger](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1527&bih=845&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=serrated+Jambiya+dagger&oq=serrated+Jambiya+dagger&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19706.22596.0.25273.2.2.0.0.0.0.74.136.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.61...0j0i30k1.dVOCuITWrSE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dual scabbard rings seem to narrow this style to North Africa, possibly a version of the Moroccan [Koummya](http://www.vikingsword.com/ethsword/koummya/).

> The koummya is the characteristic traditional dagger of the Berber and
>   Arabic peoples of Morocco.

An image from the German wiki page [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koummya#/media/File:Knife_5b.JPG):

[image]

The koummya is defined as a

> ...localized variant of the Arabic jambiya, and the contoured handles,
>   curved double-edged blades and exaggeratedly upturned scabbard tips
>   are all features consistent with such an interpretation. In the
>   context of the traditional regional manner of dress, the koummya is
>   worn visibly at the left side, generally about at the level of the
>   waist and is suspended vertically, with the scabbard tip forward, by a
>   long woolen baldric, attached at either end to one of the ***two scabbard
>   rings***, and worn crossing in front and back of the torso and over the
>   right shoulder.

Note there are many 'tourist' versions of these sold:

> Tourist grade koummyas of varying degrees of quality exist in
>   abundance and may be found at almost all arms fairs and flea markets.
>   It is difficult to walk even a block in the Marakkech market without
>   being aggressively offered the opportunity to purchase one or several
>   at "bargain" prices.

So, for other then sentimental value, a professional appraisal would probably be required.

Other similar related Items:

- [Janbiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janbiya)
- [Khanjar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khanjar)