# Can anyone tell me more about this ... sword?

Tags: weapons, sword

I am new here. I came here to ask about this small sword I found a couple of years ago. I think it used to belong to my father. 
The scabbard seems to be made of lead and the sword is currently stuck in it.
Can anybody tell me something about this sword? I keep wondering what it might be. Perhaps it was used for decoration?
Thank you :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: 
The sword is about 55 centimeter while in the scabbard. I am from Belgium, perhaps this is usefull information.
I tried taking closer pictures of the blade (both sides)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would help if you said where it was found.

Comment: It might be useful to have some idea of the dimensions - overall length, width of the blade, hilt, etc. From the image it appears to be single-edged with a fuller on the back, is that the case or is it just a trick of the lighting?

Comment: Please provide a banana for scale. Or a ruler I suppose.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with new pictures and some information.

Comment: Some features (scabbard and [fuller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuller_(weapon))) seem similar to the dagger discussed [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40059/what-kind-of-knife-is-this-and-where-is-it-from/40060#40060), from North Africa but not the shape of course.  It also resembles some forms of the [Kama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khanjali) from the Caucasus region.

Comment: If the weapon was your fathers is there any reason to place him in one of those two regions?

Comment: No, my father never went to those regions. But he collected a lot of things, including items used in the World Wars.

Comment: If the scabbard is lead, why does it have red rust on it?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Some parts seem to be made of lead. I don't know what the rest is made of. I just thought it was important to mention that lead was used.